# Routing API v7/v8 differences in response VALUES

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Here are some response samples for same requests parameters.

**Routing API v7 :**

> https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=****&app_code=*****&mode=fastest%3Btruck&summaryAttributes=traveltime%2Cdistance&waypoint0=geo%21-24.4029344635866%2C-54.1564950087283&waypoint1=geo%21-22.71237841%2C-47.3243096

```
"summary": {
             "distance": 955870,
             "trafficTime": 64619,
             "baseTime": 62804,
              "travelTime": 62804
            }
```

**Routing API v8 :**

> https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=*****&transportMode=truck&origin=-24.4029344635866,-54.1564950087283&destination=-22.71237841,-47.3243096&return=summary

```
"summary": {
             "duration": 53741,
             "length": 934637,
             "baseDuration": 53404,        
            }
```

Same `geo-coordinates`, same Mode (fastest or fast is default in v8 right ?),same transportMode (truck)
but INSANE **differences in distance, duration, baseDuration.**

**Please explain the differences between the responses of old and new apis !**

Is there a way to reduce this difference ?
What can be done here to get something equivalent of old response?

Even with routing mode slow, it's no match with old `api v7`.

This difference is hampering my ML model!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to understand why they show results so different, you need to see the complete planned route.
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=YOURAPIKEY&transportMode=truck&origin=-24.4029344635866,-54.1564950087283&destination=-22.71237841,-47.3243096&return=summary,polyline,actions

Here are the first few maneuvers (actions) in V8

```
"actions": [
{
"action": "depart",
"duration": 1958,
"length": 36251,
"offset": 0
},
{
"action": "roundaboutExit",
"duration": 3123,
"length": 68201,
"offset": 502,
"direction": "right",
"exit": 1
},
{
"action": "continue",
"duration": 1728,
"length": 36293,
"offset": 1484
},
{
"action": "turn",
"duration": 264,
"length": 3155,
"offset": 2104,
"direction": "right",
"severity": "quite"
},
{
"action": "continue",
"duration": 17,
"length": 69,
"offset": 2187
},
{
"action": "turn",
"duration": 133,
"length": 1748,
"offset": 2193,
"direction": "left",
"severity": "quite"
},
```

If you compare that to the V7 response, which is too long to post here, you will notice the route itself is different.
This is expected, because the algorithms are completely different and the default parameters for each are also different.

Now, running your queries today, the difference was smaller, so it depends on the road conditions for each day as well.

V8

```
summary": {
"duration": 41215,
"length": 902325,
"baseDuration": 40518
```

V7

```
"summary": {
"distance": 1035472,
"trafficTime": 51096,
"baseTime": 45450,
```

The parameter differences are explained here, in the migration guide:
https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html

And the rest of the differences you can read by reading each API guide, which I strongly advise.